# How to increment folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that creates a folder named TempIOFile. On subsequent runs it should recognize that the TempIOFile folder exists and create an incremented version of the folder(TempIOFile1, TempIOFile2, and so on).

I have code that works to increment the file:

```
set "baseName=TempIOFile"
set "n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%baseName%*."^|findstr /xri "%baseName%[0-9]*"'
) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
  if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /a n+=1
md "%baseName%%n%"
```

However when I try to use an `IF EXIST` statement I get an error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

```
IF EXIST %userprofile%\desktop\TempIOFile (
set "baseName=TempIOFile"
set "n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%baseName%*."^|findstr /xri "%baseName%[0-9]*"'
) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
  if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /a n+=1
md "%baseName%%n%"
) ELSE (
MKDIR %userprofile%\desktop\TempIOFile
```

)

I'm not sure why this is not working. The TempIOFile is created but on subsequent runs the incremented versions are not. Can anyone help?

Comment: I see that you understand `!` delayed expansion: Apply your understanding to _all_ variables defined inside a `(parenthesised code block)`, for instance `!baseName!` (everywhere) and `md "!baseName!!n!"` instead of `md "%baseName%%n%"`.

Comment: Write `IF EXIST "%userprofile%\desktop\TempIOFile"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as this. Unless I am not understanding your question.

```
 @echo off

 set "Num="
 :loop
 If EXIST "%userprofile%\desktop\TempIOFile%Num%\" (
    set /A Num+=1
    goto loop
 )

 md "%userprofile%\desktop\TempIOFile%Num%\"
```

Or this.

```
@echo off
set "Num="
:loop
(md "%userprofile%\desktop\TempIOFile%Num%\" > nul 2>&1) || (set /A Num+=1 & goto loop)
```